# UE 4.27 Mobile Vulkan Input Attachment Data assert on first subpass

Tags: android, rendering, assert, unreal-engine4, vulkan

I have an issue with vulkan in Unreal Engine 4.27 on android. Unreals [VulkanPipeline.cpp](https://github.com/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/blob/3abfe77d0b24a6d8bacebd27766912e5a5fa6f02/Engine/Source/Runtime/VulkanRHI/Private/VulkanPipeline.cpp#L1534) has assertion:

```
if (RemappingInfo.InputAttachmentData.Num())
{
    // input attachements can't exist in a first sub-pass
    check(PSOInitializer.SubpassHint != ESubpassHint::None); 
    check(PSOInitializer.SubpassIndex != 0);
}
```

As comment says, you shouldn't have an attachment on first subpass. While it's working on release builds it's still an issue for devs builds.
Any clues what material setup can lead to this? We are using deferred rendering.

Comment: Hi, ran into this problem myself, did you manage to fix this?

Comment: Well, no. Probably it was somehow related to PSO. Try to recollect it, if you have any